# Split string whitespace

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem. Im a begginer and Im trying to take the second part of the 'Nation' column who is written like this: 'us US' and I want to take the second part (US)

```
df['Nation'] = df.Nation.apply(lambda pos: pos.split("")[0])
```

I try it but this takes the first part (us)

Comment: [`df['Nation'].str.rsplit(n=1).str[-1]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html)

Answer (score 0):

`[0]` means the first part. Changing it to `[1]` or `[-1]` would solve the issue, but there is a better way: use `.str` methods

```
df['Nation'] = df.Nation.str.split().str[1]
```

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

I dont know why because if I do df.info I see the column like an object

Comment: @Roberto can you give a data sample to reproduce on?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your column `Nation` are mixed with some data not of string type.  In such case, **cast your column to string first** by [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) before splitting string by [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), as follows:

```
df['Nation'] = df['Nation'].astype(str).str.split().str[1]
```

or use [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`str.rsplit()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html), as follows:

```
df['Nation'] = df['Nation'].astype(str).str.rsplit().str[-1]
```